# How to hide Fault error description(WCF and Silverlight)

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have silverlight application which uses WCF for database operations. Using Fiddler I am able to tamper the parameters required for a particular method used in WCF and getting an exception "a:DeserializationFailedThe formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:parameters. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type........". My security team does not like this and saying it is exposing the real exception. Is there any way to handle this type of exception and show some user define message? If yes then please provide the complete sample. I went through so many articles in internet but none of them is having complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a custom error handler. See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599828

For lots of reference details and this

http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler.aspx

For an example that implements (in a basic, but instructive way) exactly the exception shielding behaviour you are looking for.